# display from xml file in a webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, eclipse, catalog

Update: I managed using sinatra.

In my rails application I have an xml file . I want to display it like this:
[eclipse catalog](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p)

How can I do it ? I managed to display only  as text . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have **xml file**,
write in controller

```
filepath = "#{Rails.root}/file/to/path"
send_file filepath, disposition: 'inline'
```

**:disposition** option is important!
Because specifies whether the file will be shown inline or downloaded. Valid values are 'inline' and 'attachment' (default).

Answer (score 1):

Use send_data  from controller to do same! Like show below as

```
format.xml do  
  send_data(data, :type=>"text/xml",:filename => "test.xml")  
end
```